# How to filter array of objects based on other array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I have 2 arrays of objects:

```
Array1
Array2
```

I am trying to filter Array1 by getting only items which productIds are the same as array2 item productIds

```
const filteredArray = Array1.filter(item =>
  Array2.includes(item.productId),
)
```

The above solution always returns empty array. What is wrong and how can be it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to respect the property of `array2`, because no object is equal to another primitive type, like string or number.

```
filteredArray = Array1.filter(one => Array2.some(two => one.productId === two.productId));
```